# I want to Auto add single quotes to my mysql queries

Tags: mysql, perl

I have couple of mysql queries in perl but some of the values of the where clause contain space between words e.g. the gambia. When my scripts runs with the where clause arguments containing a space it ignore the second word.

I want to know how can I solve this problem i.e. if I type the gambia it should be treated the gambia not the.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI), you can use placeholders to send arbitrary data to database without need to care about escaping. The placeholder is question mark in `prepare` statement, actual value is given to `execute`:

```
use DBI;

$dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:....",$user,$pass)
    or die("Connect error: $DBI::errstr");

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{ SELECT something FROM table WHERE name = ? });
$sth->execute('the gambia');

# fetch data from $sth

$dbh->disconnect();
```

**Edit:** If you are composing the query (as you suggested in comments), you can utilize `quote` method:

```
my $country = "AND country = " . $dbh->quote('the gambia');
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{ SELECT something FROM table WHERE name = ? $country});
```

Comment: Just to be precise about this, placeholders *do not* escape the data values. When using a prepared statement, the structure of the SQL commands and the data used by those commands are sent to the database completely separately, which eliminates the need for escaping the data entirely. This is why placeholders/prepared statements are superior to escaping: Because the data is sent separately from the commands, there is no way to trick the database into interpreting data as commands.

Comment: @Dave Sherohman - You are right, I updated wording accordingly.

Comment: For the OP, this is the right approach - you should always use placeholders rather than interpolating variables into your queries wherever possible to avoid SQL injection attacks.  Obligatory reference: http://www.bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 2):

Well, firstly, you should look at using something like [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aClass) instead of raw SQL in your application.

But if you're stuck with raw SQL, then (assuming that you're, at least, using DBI) you should use bind points in your SQL statements. This will handle all of your quoting problems for you.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('select something from somewhere where country = ?');

$sth->execute('The Gambia');
```

See the [DBI docs](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI) for more information about binding.

Comment: @bvr @davorg Thanks for your response but to make you understand more let me just attach a code snippet. I am doing something like this but assigning it to a variable and my query contain a like clause too. below is the code$sel=$dbh->prepare("SELECT `id`,`date` as day,`time`,`one`,`one_r`,`two`,`two_r`,league, country, details FROM football WHERE (one LIKE TRIM(?) or two LIKE TRIM(?)) $country $league $date $limit");
   $sel->execute("%$command%","%$command%"); $row = $sel->fetchrow_hashref(); $sel->finish();

Comment: @Sheriffo Ceesay - Please add the code into your question. Also please provide code where you are building `$country` and `$league`.

Comment: $sel=$dbh->prepare("SELECT id,date as day,time,one,one_r,two,two_r,league, country, details FROM football WHERE (one LIKE TRIM(?) or two LIKE TRIM(?)) $country $league $date $limit"); $sel->execute("%$command%","%$command%"); $row = $sel->fetchrow_hashref(); $sel->finish();